# Array timestamp not in standard format BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I created a table in BigQuery and in one of the columns I specified its mode as a `REPEATED` (array) `TIMESTAMP` column, that is `column4`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `project.dataset.table` ( column1 string,
    column2 TIMESTAMP,
    column3 ARRAY<int64>,
    column4 ARRAY<TIMESTAMP>)
```

When I insert data into that table, the `column4` converts the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` into the following format.

```
INSERT INTO
  `project.dataset.table` (column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    column4)
VALUES
  ("rowtest1", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), [5], [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()])
```

[image]

In the same query I stated the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` to `Column2` and `Column4`, but for `Column4` it changed the format of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` to `1660318705383274` instead `2022-08-12 15:38:25.383274 UTC` .

I want to keep the format as in the Column2 `2022-08-12 15:38:25.383274 UTC` for both columns, is it possible?

I want to keep the `column4` as `REPEATED` because I will use it as an `updated_at` field, to avoid redundancy in the table.

Comment: If your timestamp is "1660318705383274 " that sounds like a UNIX_TIMESTAMP and not a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ... perhaps your database settings have it set to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP instead of a default mysql date format.

Comment: Column 4 is ARRAY<TIMESTAMP>
can Col4 be CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead?

Citation -
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-unix_timestamp-function.php

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery UI seems to just display a timestamp value in an array as a format of unix timestamp. But internally, it still has a timestamp format in it.

See the query result as a JSON format.

```sql
SELECT [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP] ts;
```

[image]

And when you **UNNEST** an **ARRAY<TIMESTAMP>**, you can see it as a normal timestamp format like below.

```
SELECT ts FROM UNNEST([CURRENT_TIMESTAMP]) ts;
```

[image]